# Let $\left\{ f_n \right\} \in X^*$ such that $\forall x \in X, \left\{ f_n (x) \right\}$ converges, then $f_n(x) \to f(x)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> Let $X$ be a Banach space and $f_n \in X^*$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, be a sequence of functionals such that for any $x \in X$ the sequence $\left\{ f_n (x) \right\}$ converges. Prove that there exists $f \in X^*$ such that for any $x \in X$, $f_n (x) \to f(x)$.

This was an old analysis qual question that I could not figure out, any help would be appreciated.

At first I thought I might have to use the Hahn-Banach theorem in the proof, but I do not know if it is actually needed or not.

Comment: It's not needed. If you define $f(x) = \lim f_n(x)$, then it's easy to see that $f$ is linear. It remains to see that $f$ is continuous. Banach-Steinhaus is a standard way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment by Daniel Fischer gives all the necessary tools to solve this problem.  Here's how we fill in the details:

Define a function $f$ from $X$ to the base field by
$$f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x).$$
It is clear that $f$ is linear.  Now to show that $f$ is bounded.  Before doing this, since for each $x\in X$ we have
$$\sup_n|f_n(x)|<\infty,$$
the Banach-Steinhaus theorem applies, so there is some $M>0$ such that $\|f_n\|\leq M$ for all $n$.  Now fix $x\in X$ with $\|x\|\leq1$ and let $\varepsilon>0$ be given.  Then there is some $N$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $n\geq N$.  Thus we have
$$|f(x)|\leq|f(x)|+|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq\|f_n\|+|f_n(x)-f(x)|<M+\varepsilon.$$

Since $x\in B_X$ and $\varepsilon>0$ were arbitrary, it follows that $f\in X^*$ with norm $\leq M$, and that $f(x)=\lim_nf_n(x)$.

Comment: Thank you for the details, very clear.